# write 10 times row for passing

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, python-2.7

I changed a question little bit.Now I want to start from a Second Row Of a particular in this code only
for example:

```
IF(OR(B%s="", B%s ="", B%s =""),"C", IF(OR(B%s ="", B%s ="", B%s ="", B%s="", B%s ="", B%s ="", B%s =""), "S", ""))' %(row,row,row,row,row,row,row,row,row,row)
```

In this formula there are 10 `%s` so I had to **write 10 times row** for passing 
So I want get rid of this have it automatically count `%s` in formula and build indexing dynamically

This is the piece of code I tried.

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r"C:\Usersexample - practice.xlsx")
Sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('file1')
for row,cellObj in enumerate(Sheet['D'],1):
    cellObj.value= '=IF(OR(B%s="", B%s ="", B%s =""),"C", IF(OR(B%s ="", B%s ="", B%s ="", B%s="", B%s ="", B%s ="", B%s =""), "S", ""))' %(row,row,row,row,row,row,row,row,row,row)'
    #we1'
    #path to save file 
    wb.save(r'Documents\test3.xlsx')
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the issue you are having.  If all you want to do is count the occurrences of `%s` you can do: `count = "%sa%sa%s".count('%s')`

Comment: sorry I am not able to explain question actually  i want to get rid of passing manually %(row,row,row,row,row,row,row,row,row,row)

Comment: Then you can just do `"%sa%s".replace('%s', row)` and not using string formatting.  Or you can replace all your instances of `%s` with `{0}` and use `"...".format(row)`

Comment: Also are you using python3 or python2? Please do not tag both. They are not equivalent.

Comment: thanks yup its work

Comment: hye i want to ask one or thing

Comment: any approach on this

Comment: ? You said that worked.

Comment: yaa sorry its working